# Finding the basic and free variables of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Assuming that A is already in row reduced echelon form

$$
A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -5/3 & 6\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -3 \\0 & 0 & 0 &1 & -2/3 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(this is a row reduced echelon form matrix that i obtained from a system of linear equations, through gaussian elimination,  that used the variables x1, x2, x3, x4,x5)

from my understanding, the basic variables are  x1, x3 ,and x4. the free variables is just x2. But then we have a missing variable x5 that does not correspond to any pivot in the matrix, does this mean that x5 is NEITHER a free variable nor a basic variable

Comment: Everything except $x_1, x_3$ and $x_4$ is a free variable.

Comment: ah i understand now. So we have to use the logic that if a variable is not basic, then it must be free. thank you

Comment: Is that last column sixth column of the matrix ? Or it is the augmented column ?

Comment: it is an augmented column, sorry i forgot to mention that.